# webpack split output to vendor.js, app.js, templates.js, app.css and vendor.css

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm new to webpack and there's so many options with so little documentation that I really don't know how to continue anymore.

My application is structured in a way that makes it easy for me to build standalone components (written in AngularJS) and looks like this:

- **app/styles/** contains general stylesheets and modules which are global for the application and shared between components.
- **app/src/** contains components, such as app/src/dashboard/.
- **app/src/dashboard/** might contain .js files (which are required in index.js), scss files specific to the component in _resources/stylesheets and .html templates in _resources/views.

I am therefore trying to create multiple output files to let the browser handle cache efficiently.

So far, I managed to properly bundle files templates.js, vendor.js and app.js using the following Webpack config:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

var SplitByNamePlugin = require('split-by-name-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src/app.js')
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js'
    },

    resolve: {
        root: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "bower_components")
        ],
        alias: {
            component: path.resolve(__dirname, "app/src"),
            root: path.resolve(__dirname),
            bower: path.resolve(__dirname, "bower_components"),
            node: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
            stylesheet: path.resolve(__dirname, "app/sass")
        }
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
        ),

        new SplitByNamePlugin({
            buckets: [
                {
                    name: 'templates',
                    regex: /\.html/
                },
                {
                    name: 'vendor',
                    regex: /node|bower/
                }
            ]
        })
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.json/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            },
            /*{
                test: /\.scss/,
                loader: "style!css!sass"
            },*/
            {
                // angularjs doesn't properly export a CommonJS module, so we need to manually export the variable
                test: /[\/]angular\.js$/,
                loader: "exports?angular"
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "ngtemplate?relativeTo=" + (path.resolve(__dirname)) + "/!html"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Basically every .js file required using the **bower** or **node** alias is built into the vendor.js file, everything else goes to app.js. Everything with the .html extension gets compiled using the excellent ngtemplate-loader parser into templates.js.

This works perfectly.

Now comes the difficult part, which is to build everything **require()'d by webpack** with the extension .scss or .css **not using the alias node|bower** into app.css and every stylesheet from node|bower alias into the vendor.css file.

I've tried using the extract-text-plugin together with split-by-name-webpack-plugin to no avail, either there's a conflict between these two or I'm doing something wrong (using .extract on the .scss loader and new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css") simply didn't produce any file).

I'm pretty much lost at this point. I'd appreciate anyone pointing me into the right direction, I've wasted a week on this issue without getting anywhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To use Extract, you have to do something like this `loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader')`

Comment: That's what I used, but the Extract plugin still didn't export any file. It's most likely a problem with the Split by name plugin.

Comment: I took a look at Split's doc. It seems they only have .js examples